# If every element of A does not belong to exactly k-1 subsets in p, then p is a partition of A.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

For A = {1, 2,..., 10}, let P be a collection of k nonempty subsets of A for some positive integer k. Is the following statement true or false? If every element of A does not belong to exactly k-1 subsets in p, then p is a partition of A.

Here is my thinking:
The partition of set A is defined as the collection of non-empty subsets of A such that all the elements present in set A occur exactly once in partition of set A.

Since, every element of set A does not belong to exactly (k-1) subsets out of k subsets present in set P.

Therefore, every element of set A belongs to exactly the one remaining subset present in set P.

Hence, the set P contains every element of set A exactly once.

Therefore, P is a Partition of set A.

Hence, the statement is True.

Would I be correct?

Comment: Are you assuming the sets in $P$ form a partition of $\{1,2,\cdots,10\}$?

Comment: I am trying to figure out if P would be a partition of set A

Comment: Having thought about this, in my opinion you can conclude indeed P is a partition. (But I think the wording of the assumption needs to be more clear.)